# How to accumulate single cells from repeated rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

This is my first post, and after some problems I fixed them.
Point was, I had a CSV which I wanted to modify, relocating a cell only when the next row is repeated, in order to accumulate the values of the repeated values in only one row. If you want to work it several times repeated, you'll have to execute it that same amount of times. If someone could improve it, it would be amazing as well.

```
import pandas as pd
#df = pd.read_csv('MyCSV.csv', sep='\t', index_col=False, header=0)
#In my case, csv didn't work because of settings from read_csv
#Which looks like next serie:

data = [['LINF_01000000', 'LINJ.1:11111:222222:-', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A'], ['LINF_01000000', 'LINJ.1:122222:333333:-', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A'], ['LINF_01000000', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A'], ['LINF_02000000', 'LINJ.1:10011:2211122:-', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A'], ['LINF_03000000', 'LINJ.1:14441:666222:-', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A'], ['LINF_03000000', 'LINJ.1:77435:2543522:-', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A'], ['LINF_03000000', 'LINJ.1:544351:22543542:-', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A']]
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['LINF_MIX', 'Accession', 'Accession2', 'Accession3', 'Accession4'])
 #and then start my script here to execute:
column0 = df.iloc[:, 0]
index_Linf_Rep = 2
for LINF in column0: 
    index_Linf = index_Linf_Rep - 1
    LINF = df.iloc[index_Linf, 0]
    LINF_Rep = df.iloc[index_Linf_Rep, 0]
    if LINF == LINF_Rep:
        coordenada_repet = df.iloc[index_Linf_Rep, 1]
        coordenada_repet2 = df.iloc[index_Linf_Rep, 2]
        coordenada_repet3 = df.iloc[index_Linf_Rep, 3]
        coordenada_repet4 = df.iloc[index_Linf_Rep, 4]
        coordenada_repet5 = df.iloc[index_Linf_Rep, 5]
        coordenada_intr = df.iloc[index_Linf, 2]
        coordenada_intr2 = df.iloc[index_Linf, 3]
        coordenada_intr3 = df.iloc[index_Linf, 4]
        coordenada_intr4 = df.iloc[index_Linf, 5]
        coordenada_intr5 = df.iloc[index_Linf, 6]
        df.iat[index_Linf, 2] = coordenada_repet
        print("Hay matches")
        if coordenada_intr == coordenada_repet:
            df.iat[index_Linf, 3] = coordenada_repet2
        elif coordenada_intr2 == coordenada_repet2: 
            df.iat[index_Linf, 4] = coordenada_repet3
        elif coordenada_intr3 == coordenada_repet3: 
            df.iat[index_Linf, 5] = coordenada_repet4
            print(LINF + ' se ha repetido 4 veces')
        elif coordenada_intr4 == coordenada_repet4: 
            df.iat[index_Linf, 6] = coordenada_repet5
            print(LINF + ' se ha repetido 5 veces')
    else: 
        print('No hay match en estos dos LINF: ')
        print(LINF + ' ' + LINF_Rep)
    index_Linf_Rep += 1
        if index_Linf_Rep == 9427:
            break
#
df.to_csv('MyCSV.csv', index=False)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want to drop repeated rows or do you want to add them together/ concatenate the strings.

It's also a bit confusing because here:

```
coordenada_repet = df.iloc[index_ni, 1]
coordenada_intr = df.iloc[index_i, 2]
```

You are getting the value of the second row and second column and then the value of the first row and third column, I don't know if this is right for you.
I'd encourage you to look into pandas.Series.fill (method="ffill"), pandas.DataFrame.where (or np.where) and pandas.Series.shift

You can use a combination of creating a column that is shifted one row and loop over original and shifted to get the repeated values.

In whatever case, I believe the df.at function takes square brackets like this:

```
df.at[index_name, column_name]
```

And the df.iat function looks like this:

```
df.iat[index_index,column_index]
```

[At reference here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) and [iat reference here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html#pandas.DataFrame.iat)

In your code you are using at() so maybe try adjusting that. Do let me know about my question above, as there is likely a simpler solution

EDIT: Vectorized code

```
df_shifted = df.shift(-1)
new_df = df.copy()
new_df["Accession2"] = np.where(df["LINF_MIX"] == 
df_shifted["LINF_MIX"], df_shifted["Accession"], df["Accession2"])
new_df["Accession4"] = np.where((df["Accession2"] == "N/A") & 
(["Accession3"] != "N/A"), df_shifted["Accession3"], df["Accession4"])
new_df["Accession4"] = new_df["Accession4"].fillna("N/A")
new_df["Accession3"] = np.where(df["Accession2"] != "N/A", df_shifted["Accession2"], df["Accession2"])
df.equals(new_df)
```

You can try the vectorized code. From the error message you posted I believe the error is coming from one of the columns having the wrong data type. That or you're trying to access an iloc using a string somewhere.

Comment: Sorry. What I'm trying to do is to take the (for example): 'LINF_0100000' all together in one row, having the three accessions in the same row, but different cells. And apply this to all rows. I've tried 'coordenada_repet' and 'coordenada_intr' as .iloc with index_i and ni in order to make it variable, so it can apply to every row in the csv. I've tried also '.at', but when I put 'df.at(index_i,'Accession3') = coordenada_repet' it says 'SyntaxError: can't assign to function call'. (Also I have tried changing 'Accession3' with coordenate of column, but doesn't work either).Thanks for answering!

Comment: You need to use square brackets with at. Try doing that. If it doesn't work please update the code to reproduce your dataframe because it's wrong and throwing an error, so I can't see for myself

Comment: Hello @dasfacc , I've tried with square brackets too, but it appears: "ValueError: could not convert string to float: LINJ.1:122222:333333:-". (actually, that was the point I got stucked, because I tried "df.iat" and ".set_values" and then returned to "df.at" just to show one of those on this forum. Thank you for the attention!

Comment: On what line do you get that error? Please make sure the code you're running is the same you posted

Comment: I cannot upload the CSV in which i'm working, so it's a little bit complicated to do so, but I've edited post and tried to be more clear. Thank you again.

Comment: Hey Javier, I can't help you any further as the error is probably coming from the data. There's no part of your code that is casting strings to floats so perhaps you need to look for the faulty cell in your csv.

Comment: Hello there @dasfacc, I've made some changes and it finally works, I had to set some settings on read_csv: df = pd.read_csv('Linf_Junto_JAJ.csv', sep=',', index_col=False, header=0) 
column0 = df.iloc[:, 0]. 
(it was because of the separator on csv and header, which skips the column and didn't allowed me to refer columns as labeled). 
I'll change the whole post so everyone can consult this problem solved. Thank you again.